# PHP execute via curl_exec have Ajax request which is not working

Tags: php-curl

I made a example of my problem.
I have 4 files

1. index.php
2. RunViaAjax.php
3. SendRequest.php
4. AjaxFile.php

**index.php** File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="OK">Test Ajax</button>

       <script> 
    $("#OK").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'RunViaAjax.php',
            data: {data: "someData"}, // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**RunViaAjax.php** File

```
<?php

    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/tester/SendRequest.php',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
    ]);
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $resp;
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

?>
```

**SendRequest.php** File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script> 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'AjaxFile.php',
      data: {data: "someData"}, // serializes the form's elements.
      success: function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**AjaxFile.php** File

```
<?php 

    file_put_contents("OK-Report.php", "");
    echo "OK REPORT";

?>
```

Now by running index.php, am getting source code of SendRequest.php.
What i need is to run SendRequest.php (SendRequest.php is dynamically created file).

Comment: Not working mean your curl or ajax send request?

Comment: ajax request not working.MyFILE.php file is executing via curl_exec (and in this file is my ajax code)

Comment: Can you give clear what we need? what is your problem?

Comment: please check my question again. I edit it. Hope am more clear now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you.

```
File1.php

$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/test/MyFile.php',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
]);
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($resp);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

MyFile.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <p id="result"></p>
   <script> 
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'AjaxFile.php',
           data: {data: "someData"}, // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
            $('#result').html(data);
           }
         });

    </script>
</body>
</html>

AjaxFile.php

<?php echo 'Ajax request recieved' ?>
```

Comment: Hi, i am executing file via curl_exec where this ajax code exists... I can not hit submit

Comment: thanks for quick reply..  I tried but it's not working...  When i call MyFile.php direct via URL ajax request works. But calling it via File1.php (curl_exec) not working..  Note: MyFile.php file is executing via File1.php(curl_exec) but javascript ajax request is not working..